# Disable scrolling in a iframe

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, iframe, scroll

I need your help.

I need to disable scrolling of the iframe inside my div to use scroll of the div (I don't have the choice !).
I tried  overflow:hidden and scroling="no" but nothing is working.

Thanks for your help.

```
<div id="divPDF" style="overflow:scroll;">
  <iframe id="framePDF" width="100%"  src="data:application/pdf;base64,some64code ..." scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden;">
  </iframe>                 
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate, there was no search effort.

Answer (score 2):

You would do best via CSS:

```
iframe {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

There is no other way to do that, at least not if you want to support HTML5

Comment: With a pdf is it not possible to avoid scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try embed to display the PDF? This should work just fine in all modern browsers.

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,some64code ..." type="application/pdf" width="100%" />
```

Comment: Yes I tried it , also I tried object but it's always the same result. Thanks for your help anyway :)